# How to query for multiple extension using Windows 7 search

Tags: windows-7, windows, search

Let's take an easy example. How to build a query to find and list both *.txt and *.doc in one search?

Comment: Does the old 2000/XP way of doing things not work?

`*.txt;*.doc`

Comment: Semicolon does not work for Vista & 7.

Comment: @Mehper - just checking (we're still stuck on XP here at the office) :)

Comment: It is so frustrating that Microsoft continually changes how to use their products without letting their billions of users know.  A popup would be nice:  "Hello, user.  I see that I am a new installation of Windows-7.  Here is a list of the most common commands, all of which we at Microsoft decided to change to something completely different.  Sorry that the list is pretty long.  And thanks for being a valuable customer."

Answer (score 10):

Try typing the following query in the search box:

```
*.txt OR *.doc
```

Alternatively, you can use:

```
ext:.txt OR ext:.doc
```

Comment: Note that OR is case sensitive.